# Spring Hibernate getCurrentSession() when there's no session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

All in the title
I'm confused with how to use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

In my web-app, multi-threads are created to save messages in the DB, and on creating of each thread, I never used `openSession()` method, all of the `Daos` use `getCurrentSession()`. And till now it's working fine.

And there's no `CurrentSessionContext` configured. So does hibernate generate a new session for this thread, if not how does this `getCurrentSession work`?

**UPDATE**

Yes I'm using Spring 3.1.

Tomcat6 (as plugin in Eclipse and real server on a Linux machine, the app works on both server)

Comment: You need to tell us more about the context. Does your app run inside a Java EE app server? Are you using Spring?

Comment: @JBNizet  is there some more information you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring [HibernateTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTransactionManager.html) binds a current session to the active transaction, allowing `getCurrentSession()` to return the session associated to the Spring transaction in progress:

> PlatformTransactionManager implementation for a single Hibernate SessionFactory. Binds a Hibernate Session from the specified factory to the thread, potentially allowing for one thread-bound Session per factory. SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() is required for Hibernate access code that needs to support this transaction handling mechanism, with the SessionFactory being configured with SpringSessionContext.

Comment: So it means whenever a new `thread` is created, a new `session` will be bound to it automatically, no matter there's some DAO operations called or not? How can I debug this? where can I monitor this `session` object?

Comment: No. The transaction manager binds the session to the thread when a transaction begins.